# USING mysql prepared statement in a loop breaks the loop after excuting the first cycle/loop

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Am trying to access table names dynamically and there are many tables but it only processes for the first table and the loop breaks. Any idea what i could be doing wrongly

```
 PROCEDURE IF EXISTS pmms.TdevidendPaymentOnSavings;

  DELIMITER //


   CREATE PROCEDURE TdevidendPaymentOnSavings() READS SQL DATA BEGIN

     DECLARE accountNumber VARCHAR(30);DECLARE tableName VARCHAR(30);DECLARE 
     theAccountDate1 DATE;

     DECLARE anyDateInYear DATE;DECLARE rateUsed INTEGER;DECLARE lastDate 
     DATE;

    DECLARE ledgerBalance1 INTEGER;DECLARE amountComputed INTEGER;DECLARE 
    monthlySummations INTEGER;

   DECLARE monthlyTotals INTEGER DEFAULT 0; DECLARE l_done INTEGER;DECLARE 
    finalTotals INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE forSelectingAccountNumbers CURSOR FOR SELECT account_number  
  FROM 
   pmms.account_created_store WHERE account_number LIKE '05502%10';


      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET l_done=1;


   SET l_done=0;

  SELECT SavingsStartDate,SavingsRateUsed INTO anyDateInYear,rateUsed from 
    SavingsSharesComputationParameters;

    OPEN forSelectingAccountNumbers;


  accounts_loop: LOOP 

  FETCH forSelectingAccountNumbers into accountNumber;

  IF l_done=1 THEN

  LEAVE accounts_loop; 

    END IF;



  SET tableName=CONCAT('bsanca',accountNumber);

  CALL accountNma(accountNumber,@accountName);

  SELECT tableName,accountNumber;


  SET @sql_text1 = concat('SELECT ledger_balance INTO @ledgerBalance from  
 ',tableName,'  WHERE trn_date=@theAccountDate ORDER BY trn_id DESC LIMIT 
 1');

 SELECT @sql_text1;

 SELECT @ledgerBalance ;SELECT @theAccountDate;
 PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql_text1;
 EXECUTE stmt1;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

 END LOOP accounts_loop;

  SET l_done=0;

 CLOSE forSelectingAccountNumbers;

  END//

   DELIMITER ;
```

I have checked countless times but it seems when i remove the prepared statement and loop loops properly otherwise i seem not to find the problem.

Please help to know whether prepared statements do not work in loops 
in mysql procedures.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are reversed.

```
END LOOP accounts_loop;

SET l_done=0;
```

You need to reset `l_done` back to `FALSE` (or 0) *before* `END LOOP` -- because the `SELECT` queries *after* the `FETCH` can (not necessarilu *will* -- but *can*) also trigger the `CONTINUE HANDLER` to set it to `TRUE` (1) giving a false indication that the cursor is exhausted.